# Generate all strings up to desired length

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I want to generate all the random strings having length varying from 1 till max_length. Is is there an in-built function in python that would do that? If not, please tell me how to do this or direct me to posts which covers this type of problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This isn't really "random" strings as much as it is *all* strings, right?

Comment: One solution can be found [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/425303-generating-all-strings-of-some-length-of-a-given-a/)

Comment: That's the same as asking for all strings varying from 1 to max_length (randomness has nothing to do with it as you'll encounter all possible strings along the way).

Comment: There are a *lot* of strings for even small values of max_length, especially if you consider all possible unicode characters. Are you sure you want to generate *all* of them? Why do you need this?

Comment: sorry...i mean all the strings(not random). i need this to check the number of attempts required to estimate number of trials required to launch a brute force attack on md5 hash(part of my project)

Comment: There are 256**N different strings of length N. Why do you need to generate all of them just to calculate this?

Comment: @JustinCarrey An md5 hash is 32 chars of hex, so you have `16**32` combinations. In the current state of technology, md5 can't be bruteforced, but there exist various attacks against it, whose relevance will depend on what you want to use md5 for.

Comment: i just need to match just first 7 bits of md5 output, not the whole thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `random.sample()`:

```
In [28]: from string import ascii_lowercase as asl

In [29]: import random

In [30]: max_length=10

In [31]: for x in xrange(1,max_length+1):
   ....:     ''.join(random.sample(asl,x))
   ....:     
   ....:     
Out[31]: 'k'
Out[31]: 'jy'
Out[31]: 'ldo'
Out[31]: 'ivlr'
Out[31]: 'gqelt'
Out[31]: 'gbvnqw'
Out[31]: 'baestog'
Out[31]: 'kyijhmvn'
Out[31]: 'toshxklwb'
Out[31]: 'wihtmouexg'
```

Comment: Minor nitpick: `random.sample` returns *unique* elements, so the string is a randomly permuted subset of the alphabet (and will fail if `max_length` > `len(ascii_lowercase)`).

Comment: No, I think @nneonneo is getting at the fact the OP really wants every possible word, not simply every possible shuffle of some subset of the alphabet.  For example, you'll never get "aa".

Answer (score 3):

Random strings:

```
import random
def get_random_string(alphabet, slen):
    return ''.join(random.choice(alphabet) for _ in xrange(slen))

print get_random_string('0123456789', 5) # prints e.g. 62247
```

All strings in lexicographical order (thanks @DSM for reminding me about `itertools`):

```
import itertools
def gen_all_strings(alphabet, slen):
    it = itertools.product(alphabet, repeat=slen)
    return (''.join(s) for s in it)

print list(gen_all_strings('abc', 2)) # prints ['aa', 'ab', 'ac', 'ba', 'bb', 'bc', 'ca', 'cb', 'cc']
```

Comment: `def gen_all_strings(alphabet, slen): return (''.join(w) for w in itertools.product(alphabet, repeat=slen))`, no?  Except for changes in order.

Comment: Sometimes, I forget that `itertools` exists...you're right, it's a shorter solution. (And you can just use [::-1] if you want them in order)